# Tried to run my code on Code blocks but it showed permission denied error

Tags: codeblocks, error-messaging

When I tried to build and run in code block this is what it showed me

-------------- Build: Debug in reviewing class (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c "C:\Users\Mrs\Desktop\treasure stuff\reviewing class\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\reviewing class.exe" obj\Debug\main.o
Cannot create temporary file in C:\Users\Mrs\AppData\Local\Temp: Permission denied
Process terminated with status 3 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) .

Am using codeblocks-20.03mingw

I tried building first and then running but it did not work. I expected it to print out what I gave it to do in the console